# How does Rust detect a reference to a local variable without the function being used?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

Assume a function returns a dangling reference to a local variable:

```
fn foo<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
    let i = 2;
    &i
}

fn main() { }
```

Rust notices this and raises an error.

Adding lifetimes:

```
fn foo<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
    'b: {
        let i = 2;          // i has lifetime 'b
        &'c i
    }
}
```

Rust infers `'c = 'b` because `&i` refers to `i`. Moreover, `'a` is instantiated as `'c` and hence `'b` because the return type is `&'a i32` and the returned value is `&'c i32`. I do not see why an error should occur here, since all lifetimes can be instantiated with concrete values without any mismatches.

If `main` was

```
fn main() {
    'd: {
        let i_ref: &'d i32 = foo();    // foo() has lifetime 'b
    }
}
```

then we still would have `'a = 'c = 'b`, but in `main` there is a lifetime mismatch since `'b` does not contain `'d`. In that case, I would expect an error.

How does Rust detect the dangling reference in the first case without any invocation of `foo`?

Comment: Are you asking why dead code is getting borrow checked or are you asking how borrow checking happens at compile time and not runtime?

Comment: @isaactfa Actually none of them I'd say. I know that borrow checking is a compile-time process, but I wonder why in this specific case the compiler is so smart to notice the dangling reference without there being an explicit lifetime mismatch anywhere.

Comment: There is a lifetime mismatch though? `i` is a local variable so its lifetime ends when the function ends, which can't be compatible with the reference escaping. The function has to work for every `'a`, but the only one it can work for is the null lifetime. [Which does not exist](https://sabrinajewson.org/blog/null-lifetime).

Comment: @Masklinn I thought that `'a` gets instantiated with the lifetime of `i`... so I guess my mistake is thinking that the lifetime of `i` and `&i` is the same. But `&i`'s lifetime only starts at the line when it is returned (hence the null lifetime), right?

Comment: The lifetime is the interval between it being in scope and falling out of scope, which is at the end of the function. You can't have a reference to that existing beyond that time, it's invalid. In C you can do this, but it's *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: All generic parameters, including type parameters, lifetime parameters and const parameters, are always provided by the caller. This directly implies that any lifetime appearing in the return type must either be `'static`, or a lifetime appearing in one of the function parameter types.

Comment: I thought that the compiler chooses concrete lifetimes for lifetime parameters, so as long as there is some feasible instantiation the compiler won't complain... I feel like I need to be clearer, I have added some clarification of my understanding.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I understand the semantics behind it, but how specifically does Rust enforce these semantics? What fundamental rule of lifetimes is violated, which makes the compiler notice this dangling reference? I thought that there were a set of fundamental rules such as "`'a` only convertible to `'b` if `'b: 'a`", with which all these memory-unsafe cases are marked as an error. However, in my sample code, I fail to see what specific rule is violated.

Comment: It's hard to explain succinctly, but Rust does significant static code analysis and keeps track of the lifetime of every object being used, so it can flag anything that falls out of scope while being referenced. This is prohibited by the compiler and shows up as an error. The conversion of lifetimes is by testing if one outlives the other, all by, in effect, checking the order in which they're dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All lifetimes passed into a non-async function have to be valid for the entire function body - the lifetime can't spontaneously come into existence or become invalid during the function's execution.

This rule automatically precludes returning local references, since their lifetime effectively ends right before the function returns.

(Async functions are a bit different - under the hood, they return an opaque future object that may or may not hold the reference. But they still prevent returning references to stack allocated variables.)

---

A different way of thinking about it:

`foo<'a>() -> &'a i32` let the caller choose whatever lifetime it wants, as long as the lifetime of the (nonexistent) arguments match the return value. I could conceivably call `foo::<'static>()`, which, by the rules of the function signature, must be accepted, but obviously won't be valid for a function returning a local variable.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: `foo::<'static>()` would raise an error, I agree, for the same reason that the example from my question (which I have edited) does not work. But plugging in `'static` for `'a` happens only by calling `foo`. Hence, I do not understand why given only the function's definition and *no call*, the compiler has enough information to raise an error. What specific rule regarding lifetimes is violated by the definition of `foo`?

Comment: @cadaniluk The rule in the first part of my answer, where the lifetime must be valid throughout the function. Rust isn't like C++ where the compiler waits until template instantiation to check generics - it checks them when the function is defined.

Comment: I see. Yes, that's probably one reason for my confusion, I am thinking too much in terms of templates and substitution.

Comment: But apart from returning a local reference, how else could an input lifetime not enclose the entire function? That rule seems artificial to me in the sense that I cannot see how it prevents a larger class of errors aside from returning local references -- it is not really "fundamental."

Comment: @cadaniluk The general rule is that [references can't escape the scope for the data they reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-borrow-checker).